# How to configure plank(dock) on Lubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

Tags: lubuntu, dock, docky, plank

I just installed the plank dock app on Lubuntu 18.04.1 LTS and i have no idea where to find settings for it. Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution. You just have to right-click at the edge of the dock(at the very end of it) and the options will pop up. Hope this helps someone out there.

Comment: An extremely thin edge although.